# iOS view controller data sharing setText 'delay'

Tags: ios, objective-c, viewcontroller, settext

I have 2 View Controller's, one of them has a string (e.g. "Text1 Text2") that when a button gets pressed it saves it to default user data:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:textObject forKey:@"textObjectKey"];
```

This same button has a popover presentation segue onto the 2nd view controller that in its `viewDidLoad` retrieves the string:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"textObjectKey"];
```

and calls a `setText` method to a `textView` to contain the string.

This does work, but my problem is that when I change the string (e.g. "Text1 Text2 Text3") and click the button the textView does not show the next text until I press it again. Not only that, but if I run the project again the first time I press the button it will have the text from the last time I ran the program (until I click it again).

Is this 'delay' something I can fix? Or is it a bug with iOS (I think this only because it keeps info from the previous program execution).

Fix edit: Rookie mistake. I put the statement that stores the string in user data inside of the button method with the segue.

Comment: You're saving data to a persistent store (NSUserDefaults) and are wondering why it shows that data on the next execution of the program?

Comment: Ah ok then. Sorry I'm a bit of a noob

Comment: And the reason for your "delay" is simply that your code to set the data is called after the code to load it (try settings breakpoints).

Comment: Unless you reset the simulator/device, anything you save in the appropriate application directories or to `NSUserDefaults` will persist across runs and rebuilds of the applications. Can you post the relevant ViewController code from project?

Comment: This is the code from the view controller that loads the string from user data: NSString *textString;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    textString = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                            stringForKey:@"textString"];
    _textView.text = textString;
    
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

Comment: @sp00ky Don't post your code in comments. Update your question with further details so everyone sees it when reading the question.

Comment: You should set the text field value in `viewWillAppeae`, not `viewDidLoad`. The text field property will stil be nil at that point

Answer (score 0):

If this is all you're doing with the text, I would say it is a slow solution. Setting a property on the next controller directly would be better in my opinion. 
But, after storing to NSUserDefaults, call

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Otherwise it is written to persistent storage when it feels like it.

Comment: How does calling `synchronize` help with the delay (hint: it doesn't)?

Comment: Yeah I was doing that and it didn't make a difference

Comment: Well I thought the next vc would have to wait for the automatic periodic synchronization, which could cause a delay.

Comment: @JulianMinde The values are in `NSUserDefaults` immediately. You can read a value immediately with no delay. The persistence only affects the data being available the next time the app runs.